# unmarshal to different object using MOXy

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy, unmarshalling

I have a response xml with root element **SearchResourceResponse**. I need to unmarshal that into a different custom(HSIDetails) object.I started using MOXy as my JAXB (JSR-222) implementation. 
is my below intension correct?? is this possible with MOXy ??

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(HSIDetails.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
HSIDetails hsiDetails = (HSIDetails) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(responseXml)));
```

and my HSIDetails class

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class HSIDetails implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4352912510533245455L;

    @XmlPath("SearchResponseDetails/LogicalDevice/LogicalPhysicalResource/PhysicalResource[@*[local-name()='type' and contains(.,'icl:Slot')]]/commonName")
    private String slot;
    @XmlPath("SearchResponseDetails/LogicalDevice/LogicalPhysicalResource/PhysicalResource[@*[local-name()='type' and contains(.,'icl:PhysicalPort')]]/commonName")
    private String port;

    @XmlPath("SearchResponseDetails/SubNetwork/Pipe/commonName")
    private String telephone;

    @XmlPath("//SearchResponseDetails/SubNetwork/Pipe/lrStatus")
    private String lrStatus;

    public String getSlot() {
        return slot;
    }
    public void setSlot(String slot) {
        this.slot = slot;
    }
    public String getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    public void setPort(String port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }
    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
    public String getLrStatus() {
        return lrStatus;
    }
    public void setLrStatus(String lrStatus) {
        this.lrStatus = lrStatus;
    }
}
```

and part of my xml is:

```xml
<tns:SearchResourceResponse xmlns:tns="http://www.ICLNBI.com/ICLNBI.xsd">
    <SearchResponseDetails>
        <SubNetwork>
            <Pipe xsi:type="icl:Trail" xmlns:icl="http://www.ICLNBI.com/ICLNBI.xsd"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <CommonName>XXXXX</CommonName>
                <objectID>1234567890</objectID>
                <description>512/2</description>
                <SourceSystem>YYYY</SourceSystem>
            </Pipe>
        </SubNetwork>
    </SearchResponseDetails>
</tns:SearchResourceResponse>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the unmarshal methods that take a `Class` parameter to tell MOXy or any JAXB (JSR-222) implementation what class to unmarshal to.

```java
 JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(HSIDetails.class);
 Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
 HSIDetails hsiDetails = unmarshaller.unmarshal(
     new StreamSource(new StringReader(responseXml)), 
     HSIDetails.class).getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks @Blaise Doughan, it did work but the values comes null. I added namespace to package-info like below and updated my xpaths. **package-info** '@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace="http://www.ICLNBI.com/ICLNBI.xsd",
 xmlns={
     @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.ICLNBI.com/ICLNBI.xsd", prefix = "ns2")
 }
 )' and my xpath looks like '@XmlPath("ns2:searchResourceResponse/SearchResponseDetails/SubNetwork/Pipe/CommonName/text()") private String telephone';

Comment: I just can't get it work for the above xml, am i missing anything? null values are coming no matter what xmlpath i give. I believe the issue is not with annotations..its something else..

Comment: @user2092307 - Are you sure MOXy is being brought in as the JAXB provider.  If you do `System.out.println(jc.getClass());` what do you get?

Comment: i see this: class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl. I use maven as my build tool, so I kept jaxb.properties under src/main/resources which supposed to be in the class path. am i wrong ?

Comment: @user2092307 - That means you are getting the JAXB reference implementation.  The following example should help:  https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110322